# What is the lineage of kings in Bharata after Mahabharata war until recent day?

Tags: history

Arjuna's son Abhimanyu's son Parikshit's son Janamejaya around 5000 B.C

After that, what is the lineage of monarchy of chandravamsha (to which all Kurus belong)?

In history classes, 'India' apparently starts with Indus valley civilization, which is kinda silly, or rather the foreigner's view.

I realize this is not strictly a 'religious' question, but there was no separation of state and religion in olden days, so I'm curious at what point the ruler of Indraprastha (present day Delhi) was no longer a factor / was overthrown by non-bloodline rules.

Comment: http://trueindianhistory-kvchelam.blogspot.in/2009/08/haistinapura-empire.html?m=1

Comment: How can you say Indus valley civilization looks like foreigner's view?

Comment: @NaveenKick, I did not say "Indus valley civilization looks like foreigner's view". I said "foreigner's view is that India starts with Indus valley civlization"

Comment: @NaveenKick, i'm not sure why you are comprehending something completely different from what I said. I never said I don't believe in Indus valley civilization. It did exist. But it was not the 'start of Indian civilization'. Indus valley is just one of the settlements found by foreigners. Life in Bharat has been going on for several millions of years (actually time immemorial but putting a number for sake of understanding), through periodic cycles of yugas.